# Convert Json response in html tabular view in Powershell

Tags: html, powershell

Below is my PowerShell code snippet which is returning me valuesin three columns in the below format. I am trying to show this response by binding it in an html tag but the view is not appropriate. I tried different other options but not getting a proper tabular view.

Powershell code:

```
Function GET-AllAboutRelease{
$responseRels = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriAccount -Method get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader 
$artifactalias = @() 
foreach($art in $responseRels){
  $customartifacts = new-object PSObject -property @{
    "AID" = $art.artifacts.'alias'
    "Atype" = $art.artifacts.'type'
    "versaid" = $art.artifacts.definitionReference.version.'name'

     }
     $artifactalias += $customartifacts
     }
      $artifactalias | Select-Object `
                AID,
                Atype,
                versaid
}
```

The response I get in my debugger for artifactalias is something like this>

```
Atype {pkgmanag, git, git, build}  versaid {1.0,2.0,7.0,9.0} aid {name1,name2,name3,name4}
```

powershell constructing HTML code>

```
  Function CREATE-SECTION
    {
       #TODO- code improvement for following variable
        $myglob= GET-AllAboutRelease
        $DOWNLOAD_PAGE_BODY_CONTENT = "<!DOCTYPE html>
        `n<html>
        `n<head>
        `n  <title>Validation</title>    
        `n</head>
        `n<body>    
        `n<p>Please click the <a href=" + $($uploadResponse.webUrl) + ">link</a> to download the release.</p>
        `n<table><tr><td style='padding o 150px'>Artifactname</td><td style='padding o 150px'>Artifact Type</td><td style='padding o 150px'>Artifact Version</td></tr></table>
        `n<p></p>
        `n<table><body>$($myglob|% {"<tr><td>$($_.AID)</td><td>$($_.Atype)</td><td>$($_.versaid)</td></tr>"})</body></table>    
        `n<table><body><tr><td>$($artifactalias)</td></tr></body></table>
        `n<p></p>  
        `n</body>
        `n</html>
        `n" 

  
   
    $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+ $tokenObject.access_token)
    $headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

    $body = "{
    `n    `"displayName`":`"$release_uuid`"
    `n}"
```

the HTML which is generated is something like this:

Artifactname    Artifact Type   Artifact Version

name1 nam2 name3 name4   Pkgmanag Git Git Build  1.0 2.0 7.0 9.0

i would like this to be in a more tabular structure something like this:

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body><table><tr><td>artifact name</td><td>artifact type</td><td>artifact version</td></tr>
<tr><td>name1</td><td>Pkgmanag</td><td>1.0</td></tr><tr><td>name2</td><td>git</td><td>2.0</td></tr></table></body></html>
```

Comment: Can you show us what `$responseRels` contains? Now, it looks like you are creating a single PsObject with array values

Comment: @Theo here is my responseRels : $responseRels = id: 1914
                name: test
                artfacts: @{id= 23; definitionReference:system.object[]....}